# Understanding how AWS charges S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is not a troubleshooting question, rather a more generic one. I have read about how AWS S3 is priced - in terms of storage used, data transfer, requests and other features used. And wrt storage used, I see that we're charged for per GB stored per month. For example; In NV region, S3 standard is priced as First 50 TB/Month - $0.023 per GB.

Now, my confusion is in this scenario. Let's say I am storing some data in S3 standard in a given month of 31 days in the following way:

> Day 1: Uploading 10 GB data and keeping it for 10 days.
>   Day 10: Uploading another 15 GB data, making to a total of 25 GB, storing it
>   for 7 days.
>   Day 17: Deleting 8 GB data, making to a total of 17 GB, keeping it for another 7 days.
>   Day 24: Deleted another 5 GB data and uploaded 10 GB, making to a total of 22 GB, keeping it for last 7 days.

In this use case, how would I be charged by AWS? A clear cut explanation would be great for my understanding, and would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your "day ..." lines are contradictory between themselves. Please fix contradictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Billing section of the S3 FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/?nc=sn&loc=7#Billing):

> #### Storage Used:
>
> Amazon S3 storage pricing is summarized on the Amazon S3 Pricing page.
>
> The volume of storage billed in a month is based on the average
> storage used throughout the month. This includes all object data and
> metadata stored in buckets that you created under your AWS account. We
> measure your storage usage in “TimedStorage-ByteHrs,” which are added
> up at the end of the month to generate your monthly charges.
>
> #### Storage Example:
>
> Assume you store 100GB (107,374,182,400 bytes) of data in Amazon S3
> Standard in your bucket for 15 days in March, and 100TB
> (109,951,162,777,600 bytes) of data in Amazon S3 Standard for the
> final 16 days in March.
>
> At the end of March, you would have the following usage in Byte-Hours:
> Total Byte-Hour usage = [107,374,182,400 bytes x 15 days x (24 hours /
> day)] + [109,951,162,777,600 bytes x 16 days x (24 hours / day)] =
> 42,259,901,212,262,400 Byte-Hours.
>
> Let's convert this to GB-Months: 42,259,901,212,262,400 Byte-Hours /
> 1,073,741,824 bytes per GB / 744 hours per month = 52,900 GB-Months
>
> This usage volume crosses two different volume tiers. The monthly
> storage price is calculated below assuming the data is stored in the
> US East (Northern Virginia) Region: 50 TB Tier: 51,200 GB x $0.023 =
> $1,177.60 50 TB to 450 TB Tier: 1,700 GB x $0.022 = $37.40
>
> Total Storage Fee = $1,177.60 + $37.40 = $1,215.00

Comment: Thanks, but I am a bit confused here:
Let's convert this to GB-Months: 42,259,901,212,262,400 Byte-Hours / 1,073,741,824 bytes per GB / 744 hours per month = 52,900 GB-Months

Please help me understand this calculation. Why is it required to divide total storage byte hours with bytes per GB, and not just with hours per month.?

Comment: @serverstackqns They simply change to gigabyte-hours to get a number in the end that directly applies to the price list. If they had started the calculation with gigabyte-hours of course that wouldn’t be necessary, but their calculations start from their byte-hours measurement.

Comment: Ok Great, thank you for the guidance and explanation.